# How to get requests post body on django?

Tags: django, python-requests

requests post:

```
requests.post('http://643f3392.ngrok.io/test_linux/', data={"jsondata": "here", "you_got":"data"})
```

I want to get data like this(views.py):

```
def get_data(request):

    request.POST.get("data", None)
```

How to get {"jsondata": "here", "you_got":"data"} on django?

Comment: `request.POST` contains the data of post request. you can get all the post data  by accessing `request.POST`.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_data(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        payload = json.loads(
                  request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        # Rest of your code
```

The variable `payload` will be a dictionary.
In your case its value will be `{"jsondata": "here", "you_got":"data"}`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
     if request.method == "POST":
        json_data = request.body
```

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(["POST"])
def get_data(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        json_data = request.data
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.